# Reload shell source from script

Tags: shell, zsh

I would like to know how to reload the shell source from inside script.
I am adding some aliases inside the script and I would like to reload it at the end of it but it doesn't work until I do it manually from the terminal:

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

I have been reading that is not possible to do it because the commands are running in a subprocess which does not affect the global environment, but I would like to know if there is any workaround for it.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Don't use aliases, and especially don't use aliases from scripts. Try defining them as functions instead, perhaps in a separate file which you source from your `.zshrc`

Answer (score 1):

If a script does a

```
source SOMETHING
```

the commands in this file are executed in the current environment. This means that the definitions in this file are available afterwards. This applies of course too if you are sourcing `~/.zshrc`, so you can do it.

Whether it is a good idea to do so, is a different matter.

While zsh (different from bash) allows the use of aliases in non-interactive scripts, the whole purpose of .zshrc is to set up everything you need for an interactive environment. It is questionable whether all theses settings are applicable or at least don't hurt in the non-interactive case.

There is also a maintenance problem: Nobody expects that someone will source .zshrc from your script. The file .zshrc might be changed without thinking which scripts it will effect. You might pass your script to a co-worker who has a completely different .zshrc and so your script won't work anymore.

So, don't do that. If your script needs definitions, put them into a separate file. If you need this definitions interactively too, source that file from your `.zshrc`.

Comment: Let's explain it better. My script is adding some exports into the .bashrc or .zshrc depending of the shell used. So my intention is to make this exports effective and available after the script has finished, so I would like to find the automatic way to have them available instead of oblige to source them each time the script is run.

Comment: You want to *modify* your .zshrc from a script? You can do this, though even then, I would prefer writing the exports to a separate file and ask the user to source this file from his `.zshrc` if he wants to have this feature; I would hate it if some program modifies my carefully written .zshrc without my knowledge. But to your question: You can achieve this goal only if your script operates in the environement of the caller, i.e. you have to require that the user is sourcing your script instead of running it in a child process.